# Importance of contiguous allocation on flash disks

Tags: filesystems

All file systems I know make significant efforts to try and allocate files in contiguous blocs on a disk.

But if the disk is an SSD using flash technology underneath, is there any benefit to contiguous allocation?  The only benefit I can see is in file systems like ext4 which use extents, in which case contiguous allocation is beneficial simply because it lets us describe the file's layout more succinctly, but it seems like a fairly minor advantage.

I guess another way to write this question is: do *modern* SSDs still perform better on sequential reads and writes than on scattered reads and writes?